# Get selected date before onChange event using flatpickr

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker, onchange, flatpickr

I currently have a start date and end date date picker which gets pre-populated with dates on page load. If the user clicks the next button with out interacting with the date picker I cannot get the correct date thats in the picker and only the date as a string.

I can however retrieve the date from the onChange event but this could be to late in some instances.

Here is an example of my code to explain more:

```
startDateAccomm = flatpickr("#StartDate", {
  minDate: instance.selectedDates[0],
  dateFormat: dateFormat,
  onChange: function (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
    if (selectedDates.length > 0) {
        endDateAccomm.config.minDate = selectedDates[0];

    if (startDateAccomm.selectedDates.length > 0) {
        startDateSelected = startDateAccomm.selectedDates[0].getFullYear() + "-" + (startDateAccomm.selectedDates[0].getMonth() + 1) + "-" + startDateAccomm.selectedDates[0].getDate();
    }

    if (endDateAccomm.selectedDates.length > 0) {
        endDateSelected = endDateAccomm.selectedDates[0].getFullYear() + "-" + (endDateAccomm.selectedDates[0].getMonth() + 1) + "-" + endDateAccomm.selectedDates[0].getDate();
    }
  }

  if () {
    //do something here.
  }
}
```

I want to set the min  date to the date thats prepopulated on page load but cannot get in the correct format as **instance** is not defined until the date picker is interacted with.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After trying out the various events and hooks provided by flatpickr https://flatpickr.js.org/events/#hooks I was able to use the onReady event.

```
onReady: function (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {

        startDateSelected = selectedDates[0].getFullYear() + "-" + 
        (selectedDates[0].getMonth() + 1) + "-" + selectedDates[0].getDate();            

    },
```